# How distinguish between same class name

Tags: jquery

There are endless divs with same class name. In my example with `class="box"` and I will evaluate how many letters are in the respective box. With `$( ".box p" ).text().length`you get the number of elements in all jQuery objects. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/buscqbum/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `each()` function to loop through these elements and return the text length

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/buscqbum/4/)

```
$('.box').each(function(index) {
  var count = parseInt(index) + 1;
  $('body').append('<div>Box ' + count + ': <span>' + $(this).children('p').text().length + ' Letter</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over each `p` element and count the length of the `text()` individually. Try this:

```
$(".box p").each(function(i) {
    var n_letter = $(this).text().length;
    $("span").eq(i).text(n_letter);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jv66p42a/)

Note that I used `eq()` to relate the current `p` element to the matching `span` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each()` to iterate all p tags text and `.eq()` to get index of the span and append the text length using `.html()` into the span

```
$( ".box p" ).each(function(index) { 
    $("span").eq(index).html($(this).text().length) 
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buscqbum/3/)